# JavaScript clock font size

Tags: javascript

How can I do that hour (h) and seconds (s) font size be smaller like 40px and minutes (m) be bigger like 68px? This isn't working.

```
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getUTCHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);


    var hh = h.fontsize("40px");
    var mm = m.fontsize("68px");
    var ss = s.fontsize("40px");
    document.getElementById('ora').innerHTML =
    hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
    return i;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have to wrap your hours, minutes and seconds in HTML and give the HTML a class or a style

Comment: `h.font-size("40px");` is wrong...for a div or span element and append to your ID `ora` and add css to that div or span based on your requirement.

Comment: `x.fontSize = "1px"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would go with HTML and CSS.

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getUTCHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);

    document.getElementById('ora').innerHTML =
    '<div class="hours">' + h + '</div>' + ":" + '<div class="minutes">' + m + '</div>' + ":" + '<div class="seconds">' + s + '</div>';
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
    return i;
}

startTime();
```

```css
div {display: inline-block;}
.hours {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #999;
}
.minutes {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #555;
}

.seconds {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div id='ora'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="hours">

</div>
<div id="minutes">

</div>
<div id="seconds">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#hours, #seconds{
  font-size: 40px;
}

#minutes{
  font-size: 68px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
   function startTime() {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getUTCHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);

        document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = h; 
        document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = m;
        document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = s;
        var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
    }

    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
        return i;
    }
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1p8oekrh/5/)

Answer (score 1):

To add style you have to make them as HTML element: You can try the following way:

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getUTCHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);


    var hh = ('<text class="hour">' + h + '</text>');
    var mm = ('<text class="minute">' + m + '</text>');
    var ss = ('<text class="second">' + s + '</text>');
    document.getElementById('ora').innerHTML =
    hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
    return i;
}

startTime()
```

```css
.hour{
  font-size:60px;
}
.minute{
  font-size:40px;
}
.second{
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ora"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="ora">
</div>

<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getUTCHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);

    hh = document.createElement("span");
    hh.textContent = h + ":";
    hh.style.fontSize = "68px";

    mm = document.createElement("span");
    mm.textContent = m + ":";
    mm.style.fontSize = "58px";

    ss = document.createElement("span");
    ss.textContent = s;
    ss.style.fontSize = "48px";

    div = document.getElementById('ora');
    div.innerHTML= "";

    div.appendChild(hh);
    div.appendChild(mm);
    div.appendChild(ss);

    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) 
    {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
startTime();
</script>
```